# How is std::vector getting initialized in this case?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, stdvector, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast

I recently came across a snippet of code which stroke me as odd.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> idx;
    for (auto ii = 0; ii < 2 * 10; ii += 2)
        {
        idx.push_back ({ii, ii + 1});
        }

    auto &ind = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int> &> (idx);   
    idx.push_back ({ 40, 50 });

    for (auto ii: ind)
        {
        std::cout << ii << std::endl;
        }
    
}
```

I was sure that the code would give incorrect results, but it gave me the expected results.
A couple of observations:

1. The behaviour of reinterpret_cast is undefined in this case.
2. This is not good code
3. It worked on all the compilers where I tested it.  By work, I mean it gave me good results.

With that said, I read the std::vector implementation of VS 2019. The value of `std::vector::size()` is computed from `_Mylast - _Myfirst`.

My question is
**How is _Mylast being properly initialize?**

I read the code and couldn't find it. This is not a question about undefined behaviour but about the implementation of C++ vector.

Comment: You never gave the other guy a chance. did you?

Comment: Note that OP is asking about the specific implementation details of the standard library implementation they used to generate the behavior they describe.

Comment: `How is _Mylast being properly initialize?` Who cares? The behavior is undefined, why would you care about behavior of such code? `I was sure that the code would give incorrect results` Undefined behavior means that anything can happen. A "correct result" is any behavior.

Comment: KamilCuk, I care. Otherwise I wouldn't ask.

Comment: You can only really talk about a specific release of a specific version of a specific compiler on a specific architecture with specific flags set.

Comment: You can always look at the source code. `std::vector` has to be a header only library. Or better still post the equivalent source code and ask your question on that.

Comment: If "This is not a question about undefined behaviour but about the implementation of C++ vector." then why is the entire question everything _but_ that? If your question is "how does MSVC implement std::vector?" why are you including all this irrelevant exposition? You can read for yourself here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/vector

Comment: François Andrieux, I understand what you write, but you guys don't seem to understand English. Yes, it's undefined. Yes is bad code. But it works. I have read the std::vector implementation with a few other guys. We can't figure out how _Mylast is being initialize correctly on every freaking compiler that we have tried with over 100 variations of that snippet of code! No! This is not random behaviour. This is absolutely something that the compiler is doing or the particular template code that is very elusive.

Comment: **why are you including all this irrelevant exposition?** I have written a very clear explanation of the question. I have explained further in the comments that I tested multiple compilers. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: If you post the vector's source code that causes the effect that would be fine. That would be a concrete question about specific code.

Comment: Just don't waste your time with this question. Let it sit here, and when someone is able to answer it, I'll be very happy. What do you guys say? Just ignore it.

Comment: The typical handling of UB is to do nothing and assume the programmer knowth what the smurf they are doing. The typical `vector` is implemented as three pointers: One to the datastore (we'll call `datap`), one to the end of the datastore  so you can easily tell when you're about to shoot off the end and need to realliocate to get a bigger datastore (call it `capp`), and one pointer to the end of the data used in the datastore (endp). Typically the number of elements is a bit of generic pointer arithmetic, `endp - datap`, that will provide the number of elements between `endp` and `datap`.

Comment: @YaakovRossman You do not understand the meaning of Undefined Behavior. "I have observed it to work to work on all known compilers" does not validate your code. It shows you fundamentally misunderstand what UB means. *"This is not random behaviour."* UB does not imply random behaviour. It implies behaviour that is not specified by the language. UB can change at any time, for any reason, by changes anywhere (including outside of your code) and that all guaranties by the language **about the whole code base** are void. UB here can break code elsewhere. It voids your entire program.

Comment: Galik, I don't know what you mean by "if you post ...". I did. Is up there. You can take it compile it and run it. You're losing me.

Comment: The number of elements is computed by the size of the datatype referenced by the pointer. What you've got here is a `vector` of objects holding 3 `int`s and a `vector` of `int`s.  The size is 3 times the size, so the outcome is predictable, even though it is undefined. You could not do this with a more complicated structure, there could be padding, vtables, and other fun stuff getting in the way, and this is why folks are saying don't trust the result.

Comment: @YaakovRossman: "*How is _Mylast being properly initialize*" What does that mean? The only initialization that happens here is the creation of `idx`. Which happens by calling the default constructor. `_Mylast` is modified by calling all of the various other functions, but how it gets *initialized* is clear: read the default constructor. If you want to know how it gets its value at some point in the code, then you should explain where exactly that point is.

Comment: The `vector` implementation might not be using three pointers. It could be a pointer for data and two integers for capacity and size. It could be a Unicorn and a pile of teddy bear stuffing, if someone can figure out how to make that fit the requirements of `vector`. Whatever it's using, the results will be different. And of course the implementation could go above the call of duty and try to trap the error for you. Damned if I know how it would do that.

Comment: user4581301, thanks for giving some thought to this question. As I wrote,  size () is computed by  **_Myfinal - _Myfirst**. When the vector is cast in that manner, _Myfinal should be the last position of the std:;vector<std::array<int, 2>> which should be off from the correct value fo std::vector<int>::_Mylast. But it isn't. It's correct in all compilers. This tells me that either the actual _Mylast is being recomputed which would be impossible or the call to size () is doing something instead of the formula.

Comment: `myLast` isn't the last. It should be a one-past-the-last, and in this case the math will hold.

Comment: _Mylast is the last, or one past the end of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

The way vector gets its size in this implementation is by taking a pointer to one past the last element and subtracting from that the pointer to the beginning of the data.  That result is the number of elements in the vector.  When you do that with `idx`, You get eleven because `_Mylast` is `11 * sizeof(std::array<int, 2>)` bytes away from `_Myfirst`.  When you use `ind`, `_Mylast` and `_Myfirst` have the same values, so they are the same number of bytes apart, but they are now `int*`'s instead of `std::array<int, 2>*`'s which means that the compiler is going to treat the subtraction in terms of `sizeof(int)` which gives you the equation

```
size = 11 * sizeof(std::array<int, 2>) / sizeof(int)
```

which gives you the "correct" result of 22.  This is all undefined behavior as far as the standard is concerned, but this is why it appears to have the correct result.  If vector instead stored the size as a class member, which it is allowed to do, then you would get the same value from `idx` and `ind`.

Comment: You might be right. But this is the actual implementation of the size ()

`size_type size() const noexcept {
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
        return static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Mylast - _My_data._Myfirst);
    }`

This is what throws me off; _Mypair is never recomputed. Which std::vector seems to work very hard to maintain as elements are added or removed.

Comment: @YaakovRossman `_My_data` is not recomputed, but the pointers now have a different type, and that means the subtraction is going to give you the result of the number of bytes they are apart divided by the size of that new pointer to type, which is half the size of the old type, so you get double the size.  When you do `auto &ind = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int> &> (idx);` nothing actuall happens, `ind` just treats the data it refers to as if it were a `vector<int>`, and `vector<int>`'s size is called, which use bytes/sizeof(int) instead bytes/sizeof(array)

Comment: Nathan, thanks for the answer.  _My_data._Mylast should be pointing to the address of &idx.back () + 1 which is correct in all circumstances! Thanks for the reply. I know that the question sounded stupid, but I spent a good two days beating on it. Yes. that's why this will work on all cases where sizeof(T) == N * sizeof(W), for std::vector<T> and std::vector<W> and the vectors don't require constructor calls for the object to be properly initialized. At least, in the current implementations of std::vector that I have tried.

Comment: *"that's why this will work"* No, that is why it happened to work **this time**.

Answer (score 0):

1. The typical handling of UB is to do nothing and assume the programmer knowth what the smurf they are doing, so even if you are wrong, it takes the path of least resistance and keeps doing what it would do if you were right.
2. The typical `vector` is implemented as three pointers: One to the datastore (we'll call `datap`), one to the end of the datastore  so you can easily tell when you're about to shoot off the end and need to reallocate to get a bigger datastore (call it `capp`), and one pointer to the end of the data used in the datastore (`endp`).
3. Typically the number of elements is a bit of generic pointer arithmetic, `endp - datap`, that will provide the number of elements between `endp` and `datap`.

Visual Studio follows the typical implementation, so using a smaller array, because I'm too lazy to draw the whole damn thing, let's take a look at a `vector<array<int, 2>>` of 2 elements and a capacity of 4.

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1    |   2   |   X   |   X   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
^               ^               ^
datap           endp            capp
```

A `reinterpret_cast` looks at what is in a different light. It doesn't change any values and since both views of the `vector`s have the exact same members and those members have the exact same size `datap` for one is in the same spot as `datap` for the other. It's just going to be interpreted with a different type, and in this case a type that's half the size. So `<vector<int>>` looks like

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | X | X | X | X |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
^               ^               ^
datap           endp            capp
```

Exactly twice the size and capacity.

You could do this with a more complicated structure, but there could be padding, vtables, and other fun stuff getting in the way so that the contained `int`s don't line up perfectly, and this is why folks are saying don't trust your result. `datap`, `endp`, and `capp` will always be pointing at the same place, but if you cast to `vector<string>`, you probably won't even get a size of 1.

```
+-----------------------+-------+
|           1           |
+-----------------------+-------+
^               ^               ^
datap           endp            capp
```

In practice, The `vector` implementation might not be using three pointers. The next update of Visual Studio could implement `vector` with a pointer for data and two integers for capacity and size. Some genius could implement with the horn of a unicorn, a phoenix feather and a pile of Care Bear stuffing, if the requirements of `vector` are met. The implementation could also go above the call of duty and trap the error and warn you (Visual Studio does exactly this in the debug version of `vector` to catch out-of-bounds accesses in operator `[]`, but I don't know how it would trap lying to the compiler with a `reinterpret_cast`) or hack the Pentagon.